# Declare Property as diferent Class based on other value

Tags: vb.net, class, get, set, declare

I have: ClassUsser, ClassClient, ClassPerson.

ClassUsser

- Public Property Name as String

ClassClient

- Public Property Name as String

ClassPerson

- Public Property KindPerson as Integer
- **Public Property Person as (ClassClient or ClassPerson)**

**I want delare Property Person as diferent type of class based on value of KindPerson.**

*Enum KindsPerson
{ User=1,
Client=2}*

**First, I would set value of KindPerson, and after, through set/get methods, obtain the Person**

**I don't Know If It si posible in VB.Net. It exists any way to do this?**

Thanks

Comment: You could use inheritance.  for example ClassContact.  The ClassUser and ClassClient inherit ClassContact.  Now in ClassPerson, the person property will be ClassContact.  Would something like that work?

Comment: Mmm ok, is an option. I hadn't think on inheritance. It will be possible choose from which class inherits ClassContact when It is instanciated (client or user)?

Comment: You would declare `Person` as having the type of the base class, then assign an instance of either `ClassClient` or `ClassPerson`.  Depending on how much there is in common between `ClassClient` and `ClassPerson`, it might work better to define an `Interface` and `Implement` it instead of using `Inherits`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Factory Pattern:

```
Module Module1

  Sub Main()
    Dim p1 = Person.GetPerson(Person.PersonKind_ENUM.Client, "Adam")
    Dim p2 = Person.GetPerson(Person.PersonKind_ENUM.User, "Barbara")
    Dim personList As New List(Of Person)
    personList.Add(p1)
    personList.Add(p2)

    For Each p In personList
      Console.WriteLine($"{p.GetType.Name}: {p.name}")
    Next
    Console.ReadKey()

  End Sub

  Public Class User
    Inherits Person

  End Class

  Public Class Client
    Inherits Person

  End Class

  Public MustInherit Class Person
    Property Name As String
    Public Enum PersonKind_ENUM
      User
      Client
    End Enum
    Public Shared Function GetPerson(personKind As PersonKind_ENUM, name As String) As Person
      Select Case personKind
        Case PersonKind_ENUM.Client
          Return New Client() With {.Name = name}
        Case PersonKind_ENUM.User
          Return New User() With {.Name = name}
        Case Else
          Throw New InvalidOperationException
      End Select
    End Function
  End Class
End Module
```